# find variables that have significant difference between two groups?

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, mathematical-statistics

I have two grouped data sets with too many variables. As a pretest, I would like to find variables which show significantly difference between the groups. What kind of simple test I can do?

Comment: So, I dig the fact that you collected a lot of data. But why would you want to cherry pick variables to show that two groups are different? That is just a bad way to go about the scientific process. Perhaps you suspect that there are certain traits of the two groups that differ from one another? The answer to your question truly depends on the context, without it there is no mathematical equation or test that will help.

Comment: This could be called exploratory analysis. I do not see anything wrong in trying to find variables which show significant differences. But one needs to correct for multiple testing. Also the findings can only be called hypothesis generating and not confirming.

Comment: @rnso I should clarify; you are correct, there is nothing wrong with showing that significant differences exist between groups. What I mean to say is that we should not go into the analysis with the intention of proving a particular outcome. I.e. I want to prove Group A is different than Group B, therefore I will ignore any evidence that suggest Group A is similar to Group B.

Comment: After reading this question a few more times, I think I might have a better idea of what you are asking if you could explain the context a bit more. Is this a classification task? Are you trying to explain a something using regression?

Comment: @k6adams Thank you for your comments. I understand what you are saying. I am doing this work as an explanatory test. I have too many independent variables so I just wanted to get some idea for doing the initial test for understanding the data. I know test can be varied depending on the observations such as discrete continuous dummy or how the two group is different.. Correlation test, logit or regression may be also my explanatory test. Any way thanks.